# Calculator's view on the non-permissible values of the expression $\frac{1}{\frac{x}{x-1}+x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, divisibility

When I try to find the non-permissible values of the expression $$ \cfrac{1}{\frac{x}{x-1}+x}$$ I rewrite it as

$$\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{x^2}{x-1}}$$

and conclude that the **non-permissible values are** $x = 0$ and $x=1$ as those values will make the denominators present in the expression undefined.

But this expression can also be written with the $\div$ symbol and then, using the "division is multiplying by a reciprocal," we can have  $$1 \div \frac{x^2}{x-1} \stackrel{\text{multiply by recip}}{\implies} 1 \cdot \frac{x-1}{x^2}$$ and then one could conclude that $x=0$ is the **only non-permissible value.**

Three different calculators accept this claim:

(1) **A TI-89**

[image: TI-89 picture]

**(2) Desmos graphing calculator,**

[image: Desmos picture]

**(3) Google calculator**, with $1 \div (1 \div (1-1) +1)$:

[image: Google calculator picture]

These three calculators seem to have no problem with the simplification of $$\cfrac{1}{\frac{x}{x-1}+x} = \frac{x-1}{x^2}$$ as they all treated $x=1$ as a permissible value (i.e. no errors).

What is happening here? Is my initial conclusion of the non-permissible values being $x = 0$ and $x=1$ correct?

I have heard that Desmos and other graphers may simplify the original expression to make operations more efficient, but I am not sure how this might apply to the Google calculator.

(Oddly enough, my Windows calculator gives me a divide-by-zero error for $1 \div (1 \div (1-1) +1)$.)

Comment: You are right. Both $x=1$ and $x=0$ need to be excluded. I'm not sure what is happening here though

Comment: "division by $k$ is multiplying by the reciprocal $1/k$" is only true if $k \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

They are different functions since they have different domains.  But, they agree on whatever numbers are common to their domain.  By simplifying to 
$$
\frac{x^2}{x - 1}
$$
you are changing to a new function.  For example, if I say your function is to take a number, $x$, divide $1$ by it, then divide $1$ by that result, you will get:
$$
x \mapsto \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}.
$$
I could then define a different function that just repeats the input:
$$
x \mapsto x.
$$
For $x \neq 0$, they agree.  But, the first cannot be computed at $x = 0$.